# Cannot reconstruct Image after manipulation of pixels Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I need to crop an image if it exceeds a certain dimension limit.

In a nutshell, I am grabbing the user uploaded image, checking the dimension of the image drawing it on a canvas and extracting the data using getImageData.

I am then looping through the Row-Major returned data and storing the rgba values in an array.

To perform the cropping I am looping through the dimensions of the original size, checking if the current position is within the desired cropped dimension, if so, storing the data from the original image, into a new image.

Here is the code that is meant to perform the above:

```
let groupedData = []
    for (let i = 0; i < img.data.length; i += 4) {
        //img is in Row-major order
        groupedData.push({
            r: img.data[i],
            g: img.data[i + 1],
            b: img.data[i + 2],
            a: img.data[i + 3]
        })
    }

    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    canvas.width = img.width - cropX        // canvas.width = img.width
    canvas.height = img.height - cropY      // canvas.height = img.height
    
    

    let newImage = ctx?.createImageData(img.width - cropX, img.height - cropY)
    // let newImage = ctx?.createImageData(img.width, img.height)

    if (newImage) {
        let a = 0
        let b = 0
        for (let x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
            for (let y = 0; y < img.height; y++) {
                if (
                    x >= Math.floor(cropX / 2) &&
                    x < Math.floor(img.width - cropX / 2) &&
                    y >= Math.floor(cropY / 2) &&
                    y < Math.floor(img.height - cropY / 2)
                ) {

                    newImage.data[b] = groupedData[a].r
                    newImage.data[b + 1] = groupedData[a].g
                    newImage.data[b + 2] = groupedData[a].b
                    newImage.data[b + 3] = groupedData[a].a

                    b += 4
                }
                a++
            }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(newImage, 0, 0)
    }
```

Running the above code yields this result :

[image]

On the other hand, if I replace with the commented code and remove the condition inside the loop, I get this result :

[image]

Clearly I am doing something wrong within the loop but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You should be able to crop and draw the image using a single call to ctx.drawImage.  See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-crop-an-image-using-canvas/amp/

Comment: Thanks! This made it much easier.

Comment: At least one problem with your loop (I didn't try to run your code), is that you're still iterating over the original number of pixels, not over the new cropped one. So if we say original is 300x300 and cropped is 100x100, when you reach the pixel at index 101, it should be the coords (0,1) but your loop treats it as the coords (101,0). Change your loops to `for (let x = 0; x < img.width - cropX; x++) {  for (let y = 0; y < img.height - cropY; y++) {`